# Can I access Worldclim 2.1 CMIP6 data in 30-second resolution?

Tags: raster, r, climate

I am trying to access the Worldclim 2.1 CMIP6 future climate data at 30-second resolution. The Worldclim website says 30-second data will be available by then end of March 2020. This is long overdue and I am not sure if maybe there is another way of accessing it or similar downscaled CMIP6 data?

I have tried emailed their support email a few times over the last several months with no response.

If not possible, I'm looking for similar downscaled data for different CMIP6 SSPs (for the Arctic in particular) if anyone has directions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the CMIP6 data for 30s is available anywhere else at this time. If you are looking for modelled data with such spatial resolution, the only data available is SMIP5 via https://www.worldclim.org/data/v1.4/cmip5_30s.html

But I am also hoping the developers will deposit the data soon. Because it is already over a year past when the data is expected to be released.